# PHP Session and Cookie Issues

Tags: php, session, cookies

I want to save and remember multiple words as a string in either a cookie or session and redisplay them in a value field of an input in a html table.

For example,

Say I want to store "John Smith" in `$_SESSION['Customer']` or

```
setcookie("Customer", "$CUSTOMER", $time);
```

And that redisplays the full string in a p tag. But when I want to display the full in an input field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="customer" value= <?php echo $_COOKIE['Customer'];?>

<input type="text" name="customer" value= <?php echo $_SESSION['Customer'];?>
```

And these display the first word but thats all. Know why it wont display both words?

Have you checked out a rental car recently? Are you Gary Cole?

Customer: Gary  (should be Gary Cole)
Car Name: Ford  (should be Ford Focus)

Maybe its a table problem?

Comment: Is the invalid php & html a typo or is that the problem? You need `"` around attribute values and `<` and `>` to delimit the html tag.

Comment: make sure that the no headers are being sent before the setCookie function

Comment: The < tags were okay it just made it vanish before when making this thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for removing the question ... now all the replies are total wastes of time.

Comment: @James, it's not permitted to self-destruct the post the way you tried, **especially after someone took the time to provide an Answer**. Sorry, but I've rolled back to its previous state. Open a support thread at [meta] if you have any concerns regarding this.

Comment: @PhilPerry, you can flag for Moderator attention when you see this happening. Select "other" in the popup and explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe two things:

1. Invalid HTML & PHP: missing `"` and `<` and `>`. Valid is:

   ```
   <input type="text" name="customer" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['Customer']; ?>" />
   ```

   **Be sure to html encode that value!**, i.e.:

   ```
   <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['Customer']); ?>
   ```

   or with short tags:

   ```
   <?= htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['Customer']) ?>
   ```
2. When a cookie is set, it doesn't update `$_COOKIE`, so you can't access it immediately. It exists in `$_COOKIE` on the next page load. Or you can add it yourself, directly:

   ```
   $_COOKIE['Customer'] = "$CUSTOMER";
   setcookie("Customer", $_COOKIE['Customer'], $time);
   ```

And of course setcookie() doesn't affect `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it still does not work.                       Have you checked out a rental car recently? Are you Gary Cole?
 
Customer: Gary
Car Name: Ford                                                       Maybe its a table problem?

Comment: What??? I've no idea what you're talking about. What doesn't work? The cookie isn't set? You can check that in your browser's devtools' Network panel. And of course by `print_r($_COOKIE);` on the next page. And by any PHP errors. Is error reporting on?

Comment: Yes. Some markup might help. Have you read the answer? Have you added the `"`?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$CUSTOMER = "John Smith";
setcookie("Customer", "$CUSTOMER", time()+3600);
echo $_COOKIE['Customer']; // check cookie ;-)
?>
<form>
<input type="text" name="customer" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['Customer']; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: That displays John and Smith for you? It doesnt for me. But I am starting to think it being in a table is something to do with it

Comment: Yes it does, you have to refresh first ofcourse because the cookie must first been set but after that John Smith shows inside the input field. I think your problem is somewhere else indeed.